# Как реализовать перегрузку индексатора [ ]?

Tags: c#, перегрузка-операторов, операторы, переопределение

Необходимо перегрузить индексатор [ ], так чтобы мы могли выводить потом отдельно день, месяц и число.Как это реализовать? В представленном ниже коде есть перегрузка + и - для прибавления или вычитания дней из даты.

```
      using System;
      using System.Collections.Generic;
      using System.Linq;
      using System.Text;
      using System.Threading.Tasks;

  namespace oop4
{
class DateHelper
{
    int day;
    int month;
    int year;
    static int[] daysInMounth = { 31, 28, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31 };

    public DateHelper(int d, int m, int y)
    {

        if (!isValidDate(d, m, y))
        {
            throw new noValidateDate("Неправильная дата");
        }
        day = d;
        month = m;
        year = y;

    }


    static bool isValidDate(int day, int month, int year)
    {
        int MAX_DAYS = 0,
            MAX_VALID_YR = 2500,
            MIN_VALID_YR = 0;
        switch (month)
        {
            case 1:
            case 3:
            case 5:
            case 7:
            case 8:
            case 10:
            case 12:
                {
                    MAX_DAYS = 31;
                    break;
                }
            case 4:
            case 6:
            case 9:
            case 11:
                {
                    MAX_DAYS = 30;
                    break;
                }
            case 2:
                {
                    if (isLeapYear(year)) MAX_DAYS = 29;
                    else MAX_DAYS = 28;
                    break;
                }
        }

        if ((day < 1 || day > MAX_DAYS) || (month < 1 || month > 12) || (year < MIN_VALID_YR || year > MAX_VALID_YR))
        {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    static bool isLeapYear(int year)
    {
        return ((year % 4 == 0 && year % 100 != 0) || year % 400 == 0);

    }
     public string showdata(int c)
       {
        string dat = "";
        string[] marr ={" января "," февраля "," марта "," апреля "," мая 
      "," июня "," июля "," августа "," сентября "
            ," октября "," ноября "," декабря "};
        switch (c)
        {
            case 2:
                dat = Convert.ToString(day + "." + month + "." + year); break;
            case 3:
                dat = Convert.ToString(day + "." + month + "." + year % 100); break;
            case 4:
                dat = Convert.ToString(day + " " + marr[month - 1] + " " + year); break;
            default: break;
        }
        return dat;
    }

       public static int operator -(DateHelper D, DateHelper T)
    {
        int result;
        result = (int)D - (int)T;
        return result;

    }

       public static explicit operator int(DateHelper d)
    {
        int LeapYears;
        int daysBeforeCurrentYear;
        int daysInCurrentYear = 0;

        LeapYears = d.kolvoLeapYear(d);
        daysBeforeCurrentYear = (d.year - 1) * 365 + LeapYears;
        for (int i = d.month - 1; i >= 1; --i)
        {
            if (isLeapYear(d.year))
            {
                if (i == 2)
                {
                    daysInCurrentYear += (daysInMounth[i - 1] + 1);
                }
                else
                {
                    daysInCurrentYear += (daysInMounth[i - 1]);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                daysInCurrentYear += daysInMounth[i - 1];
            }
        }
        return daysBeforeCurrentYear + daysInCurrentYear + d.day;

    }

    int kolvoLeapYear(DateHelper d)
    {
        int countYear = 0;
        int minYear = 0;
        int maxYear = d.year;
        for (int i = minYear; i < maxYear; ++i)
        {
            if (isLeapYear(i))
                ++countYear;
        }
        return countYear;
    }

    public string dayWeek(DateHelper D)
    {
        DateHelper T = new DateHelper(1, 1, 2001);
        int i = (D - T) % 7;
        string[] dweek = { "Понедельник", "Вторник", "Среда", "Четверг", "Пятница", "Суббота", "Воскресенье" };
        return dweek[i];
    }
    //public static возвращаемый_тип operator (параметры)
     public static DateHelper operator +(DateHelper D, int d)
    {
        int m = 0;
        while (d != 0)
        {
            if (isLeapYear(D.year) && D.month == 2) m = daysInMounth[D.month - 1] + 1;
            else m = daysInMounth[D.month - 1];

            if (D.day + d <= m)
            {
                D.day += d;
                d = 0;
            }
            else
            {
                d -= m - D.day;
                D.day = 0;
                if (D.month + 1 > 12)
                {
                    D.month = 1;
                    D.year++;
                }
                else
                {
                    D.month++;
                }
            }
        }
        return D;
    }

    public static DateHelper operator -(DateHelper D, int d)
    {
        while (d != 0)
        {
            if (D.day - d >= 1)
            {
                D.day -= d;
                d = 0;
            }
            else
            {
                d -= D.day;
                if (D.month - 1 == 0)
                {
                    D.month = 12;
                    D.year--;
                }
                else
                {
                    D.month--;
                }
                if (isLeapYear(D.year) && D.month == 2)
                {
                    D.day = daysInMounth[D.month - 1] + 1;
                }
                else
                {
                    D.day = daysInMounth[D.month - 1];
                }

            }
        }
        return D;
    }



    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int c, p, day, month, year;
        DateHelper date = null, date2 = null;

        DateHelper d1 = new DateHelper(1, 1, 1);
        DateHelper d2 = new DateHelper(1, 1, 1);
        Console.WriteLine(d1 + (int)d2);
        do
        {
            Console.Clear();
            if (date != null)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Введеная дата: " + date.showdata(4));
            }
            Console.WriteLine("1.Ввести дату\n" +
            "Вывести дату в формате:\n" +
            "  2.10.10.2010\n" +
            "  3.10.10.10\n" +
            "  4.10 октября 2010\n" +
            "5.Вычитание одной даты из другой\n" +
            "6.День недели заданной даты\n" +
            "7.Прибавить n дней\n" +
            "8.Отнять n дней\n" +
            "\n0.Выход");
            try
            {
                c = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            }
            catch (Exception notValidEnter)
            {
                c = -1;
            };
            switch (c)
            {
                case -1:
                    Console.WriteLine("Неверный ввод");
                    break;
                case 1:
                    {
                        bool flag = false;
                        do
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine("Введите число:"); day = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
                            Console.WriteLine("Введите месяц:"); month = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
                            Console.WriteLine("Введите год:"); year = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
                            try
                            {
                                date = new DateHelper(day, month, year);
                                flag = true;
                            }
                            catch (noValidateDate ex)
                            {
                                Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
                            }

                        } while (!flag);
                        break;
                    }
                case 2:
                    Console.WriteLine(date.showdata(2)); break;
                case 3:
                    Console.WriteLine(date.showdata(3)); break;
                case 4:
                    Console.WriteLine(date.showdata(4)); break;
                case 5:
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Введите дату, которую будем вычитать:");
                        bool flag = false;
                        do
                        {

                            Console.WriteLine("Введите число:"); day = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
                            Console.WriteLine("Введите месяц:"); month = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
                            Console.WriteLine("Введите год:"); year = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
                            try
                            {
                                date2 = new DateHelper(day, month, year);
                                flag = true;
                            }
                            catch (noValidateDate ex)
                            {
                                Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
                            }

                        } while (!flag);
                        Console.WriteLine(date - date2);
                        break;

                    }
                case 6:
                    Console.WriteLine(date.dayWeek(date)); break;
                case 7:
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Введите число дней, которое нужно прибавить:\r");
                        p = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
                        date = date + p;
                        break;
                    }

                case 8:
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Введите число дней, которое нужно вычесть:\r");
                        p = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
                        date = date - p;
                        break;
                    }

            }

            Console.ReadKey();

        } while (c != 0);
    }
}
class noValidateDate : ArgumentException
{
    public noValidateDate(string message)
        : base(message)
    { }
    }
 }
```

`

Comment: а зачем именно индексатор, почему не просто 3 свойства/геттера (перегрузить можно так https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/indexers/using-indexers)?

Comment: Потому что так по заданию требуется